# sed regular expression does not work as expected. Differs on pipe and file

Tags: regex, linux

I have a string in text file where i want to replace the version number. Quotation marks can vary from `'` to `"`. Also spaces around `=` can be there and can be not as well:

```
$data['MODULEXXX_VERSION'] = "1.0.0";
```

For testing i use

```
echo "_VERSION'] = \"1.1.1\"" | sed "s/\(_VERSION.*\)[1-9]\.[1-9]\.[1-9]/\11.1.2/"
```

which works perfectly.

When i change it to search in the file (the file has the same string):

```
sed "s/\(_VERSION.*\)[1-9]\.[1-9]\.[1-9]/\11.1.2/" -i test.php
```

, it does not find anything.

After after playing with the search part of regex, i found one more odd thing:

```
sed "s/\(_VERSION.*\)[1-9]\./\1***/" -i test.php
```

works and changes the string to `$data['MODULEXXX_VERSION'] = "***0.0";`, but

```
sed "s/\(_VERSION.*\)[1-9]\.[1-9]/\1***/" -i test.php
```

does not find anything anymore. Why?

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 desktop.

Anyone can explain what am I doing wrong? What would be the best command for replacing version numbers in the file for the string `$data['MODULEXXX_VERSION'] = "***0.0";`?

Comment: The second one doesn't find anything because `[1-9]` does not match `0`. Use `[0-9]`

Comment: @hek2mgl nice catch :D. I couldn't find that too. That's the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `[1-9]` doesn't match the `0`s in the version number. You need to use `[0-9]`.

---

Besides that, you may use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -r 's/(.*_VERSION['\''"]]\s*=\s*).*/\1"1.0.1";/' conf.php
```

This doesn't look at the current value, it simply replaces everything after the `=`.

I've used `-r` which enables *extended posix regular expressions* which makes it a bit simpler to formulate the pattern.

Another, probably cleaner attempt is to store the *conf.php* as a template like *conf.php.tpl* and then use a template engine to render the file. Or if you  really want to use `sed`, the file may look like:

```
$data['FOO_VERSION'] = "FOO_VERSION_TPL";
```

Then just use:

```
sed 's/FOO_VERSION_TPL/1.0.1/' conf.php.tpl > conf.php
```

If there are multiple values to replace:

```
sed \
  -e 's/FOO/BAR/' \
  -e 's/HELLO/WORLD/' \
  conf.php.tpl > conf.php
```

But I recommend a template engine instead of `sed`. That becomes more important when the content of the variables to replace may contain characters special to regular expressions.